# One line encrypt/decrypt of querystring in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, query-string

I'm looking for a one-line PHP encrypt/decrypt function that is reasonably secure (more than simply obfuscating with base64) and where the string can be passed via GET without being mangled at the other end.

I tried the following, but am not having any luck with the decrypted string:

```
$string = 'domain.com|path|lang|010502599040475829162|'.$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$encrypt = base64_encode(mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, 'A41Hfls', $string, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT));


$decrypt = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, 'A41Hfls', base64_decode($_GET['encrypt']), MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
echo $decrypt;
```

Output: ~�K�_��8�E��*撺p)특t`��;-�&f͂p�>Q���r�����O�8����o�f�>?�

Comment: Are you actually passing the string by `$_GET` in the last two lines?

Comment: I've located the issue but I'm not sure how to solve it. When I pass the base64_encoded string over GET, it looses characters such as + and =, so when I attempt to decode, it gets really messed up.

I'm wondering if I should urlencode/decode the string as well or is there a better way of turning an encrypted string into something that is querystring friendly?

Answer (score 0):

Try [urldecoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) the string first

```
$encrypt = base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['encrypt']));
$decrypt = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, 'A41Hfls', $encrypt, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
```

Comment: Check your environment first! There are some shared hostings where the Mcrypt is disabled ...

Comment: I believe I had to urlencode() the query string, but not urldecode() the $_GET result in the end.

Comment: And you have tested this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending request from URL then you need to do following on the server.

$data_encrypt = $_GET['data_encrypt'];

//look for spaces and convert them into +
// the reason is when you send request to server using url sometime it converts the + to  spaces.
$data_encrypt= str_replace(" ","+",$data_encrypt);

$data_decrypt=mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES,'A41Hfls',base64_decode($data_encrypt), MCRYPT_DECRYPT);

One another thing enable utf8 encodings where you are redering this output.